# Why is compiling TypeScript on Mac much faster than on PC?

Tags: windows, macos, typescript, typescript1.5

A project takes my ThinkPad X1 (i7-5500U 2.4-3.0GHz + 512G PCI-e SSD, Windows 10 build 10074) about 5 seconds to compile takes only 3 seconds on a i5 MacBook Pro (2.6GHz), and less than 6 seconds on a low end MacBook Air.

What's making this huge difference here?

Comment: You're using a beta OS? Different compilator optimization? Different system ressources allocations? There is a *lot* of possible cause

Comment: Beta OS, yes, or preview, same compiler options. It takes me a full core (50%) when compiling.

Comment: And maybe Mac OS compilator is multi-threaded

Comment: Just monitored the CPU usage on my workmate's i5 Mac, it takes only about 20% of the CPU.

Comment: My guess would be the disk - the SSDs in MacBooks are stupid fast!

Comment: My PCI-e SSD writes 1.2GB/s.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript has a "diagnostics" flag that will log out the time various compiler pipelines (file system, parsing, binding) take. I suspect a better Unix support by node/iojs.

Comment: Thanks, just tested that out. The most significant difference is on emit time (2.3s vs 0.5s) and IO write (1.61s vs 0.09s), not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Just tried turning off Windows Defender, and it gets slightly faster, especially IO write time.